# 3D contour mesh computation

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh-generation, mesh, visualization, 3d

I have the value of a function in three dimensions, $f(x, y, z)$, which varies smoothly.

I would like to compute a 3D mesh where $f(x, y, z)$ has a particular value.

Are there algorithms to do this? (And if so, any implementations?)

---

Note: This is the 3D equivalent of finding a contour of a 2D function, $f(x, y)$:

[image: 2D contour examlpe]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could use the "marching cubes" algorithm. If memory serves, it requires a grid of samples as input, so at the very least you should be able to sample your function and run the algorithm as-is. You also might be able to modify the algorithm to callback to f directly. There's a popular implementation at http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/ that might help you get started.

Comment: Thanks! For others, I used an implementation in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the voxel-based approach that rchilton suggests, you could also look at Delaunay-type algorithms. For example, the Computational Geometry Algorithms Library (CGAL) has some built-in functionality for surface mesh generation with examples [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html). You could also try [distmesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/), the essential idea of which has been ported to a number of other libraries and programming languages. There's also an interesting [blog post](https://mirams.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/quick-and-easy-meshing/) about getting distmesh3d to work just right.